# np.linalg.svd hangs if tensorflow imported, even if it is not used in any way

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, python-3.6, svd

I found, that [np.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) hangs on my data under strange an unexplainable circumstances.

The code below loads my data from pickle file and applies numpy's SVD to it:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pickle

import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version: ", tf.__version__)

print("Python: ", sys.version_info )

print("Numpy config show:")
np.__config__.show()

with open('M_matrix.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    M_matrix = pickle.load(f)['M_matrix']
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(M_matrix, full_matrices=False)

print("Done.")
```

The code behavior is following:

1) If tensorflow is imported (although it is never used), and python environment is 3.6, then the code hangs on numpy's SVD.

2) If tensorflow is NOT imported, the code does not hang (Done printed) in either python 3.5 or python 3.6 environment.

3) If python environment is set to 3.5, the code does not hang even if tensorflow is imported.

Tensorflow version reported is always 1.3.0, so I suspect, that some of binary versions of tensorflow is poisoning numpy's SVD somehow.

Does someone have any ideas how to control this behavior?

Comment: My incomplete list of imprecise problem-descriptions: (1) does not work (2) hangs.

Comment: @sascha I am very sorry for this, but the problem is of this kind itself

Comment: (1) If multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK is used, i would expect indeterministic results. (2) There are some issues at numpy's github compatible to this in general, but mapping from your problem might be hard (3.5 vs. 3.6 etc.; make sure the data it's working on is bitwise-equivalent).

Comment: @sascha how to check LAPACK used? looks like I use defaults

Comment: @sascha I havend observed indeterministic behavior! if script runs, then it runs any number of times I run it! and if it doesn't run, it doesn't run any time I run it!

Comment: Indeterministic behaviour is not just about the result! Look, there are tons of braindead things to try, but i don't think SO is the right platform for this kind of step 1 step 2 step 3 stuff. As a start: hash your matrices to make sure data is bit-identical; turn off threads in BLAS/LAPACK. Try and see. That's what i would do first.

Comment: @sascha data is bit-identical, I checked

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Anaconda from archive [in version 4.2.0](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh) with python 3.5 inside then I have installed tensorflow-gpu with pip, not with conda.

And glitch disappeared.